# A Very Short Question On Surd Notation{Square Root}

Tags: arithmetic

What makes $\sqrt[7]{9}$ = $9^\frac{1}{7}$ Can this be explained using laws of indices?

Comment: +1. I always took $\sqrt[n]{x} = x^{\frac{1}{n}}$ for granted!

Comment: -1. What is your definition of $x^{1\over n}$? How is it related to $\sqrt[n]{x}$? Without knowing what is meant, there is no point in using various formulas!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, do you agree that $\sqrt[7]9$ is a number such that $(\sqrt[7]9)^7=9$?

Now, suppose $$\begin{align*}\sqrt[7]9&=9^x\\ (\sqrt[7]9)^7&=(9^x)^7 \tag 1\\ 9^{7x}&=9 \tag 2\\7x&=1 \tag 3\\ x&=\dfrac 1 7\end{align*}$$

We have used in going from $(1)$ to $(2)$ that,

$$(x^a)^b=x^{ab}$$

In going from $(2)$ to $(3)$ we use the fact that, $$x^a=x^b \implies a=b$$

Answer (score 3):

$(9^{1/7})^7 = 9^{(1/7) \cdot 7} = 9^1 = 9$

This shows that $9^{1/7}$ really is a 7th root of 9.

In general, $(x^{a})^b = x^{ab}$.  Assuming $x \geq 0$ and $a > 0$ an integer, we can use this to see that, more generally,

$$\sqrt[a]{x} = x^{1/a}$$

Does that answer your question?

Comment: how come $(9^\frac{1}{7})^7 = 9^[(\frac{1}{7})\dot7]$?

Comment: @alok $(x^a)^b = x^{ab}$ for $x \geq 0$ and $a, b$ real numbers, is a general fact, the proof of which requires calculus.  It is in most calculus books.  At lower levels, it is just given as a fact.  You can prove it for $a, b$ positive integers using induction.